# Unable to change VisualStateManager transition duration

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, visualstatemanager

I've defined a few `VisualStates` for a control I'm creating to fade in an overlay ("ThankYouOverlay") with a message:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition To="ThankYou" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="ThankYou">
            <Storyboard>
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

This transition is working, but I'm unable to change the animation duration.  I've played with different combinations of the `VisualTransition`'s `GeneratedDuration` property and the individual animations' `Duration` properties, but regardless of these changes, the actual duration of the animation lasts 1 second (the default, I'm assuming).

What am I missing?  How can I change the transition's duration?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to try and prove this point to a coworker, I specified a `Duration` on **every** available `Duration` property... and then it worked the way I expected:

```
<VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
    <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
        <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualTransition To="ThankYou" GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.3">
                <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.3">
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1" />
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualTransition>
        </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
        <VisualState x:Name="Normal">
            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.3">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="0"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
        <VisualState x:Name="ThankYou">
            <Storyboard Duration="0:0:0.3">
                <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)">
                    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0:0:0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Visible}"/>
                </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:0.3" Storyboard.TargetName="ThankYouOverlay" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" To="1"/>
            </Storyboard>
        </VisualState>
    </VisualStateGroup>
</VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

I'm not really sure which of these are necessary and which are redundant.

Comment: Your VisualTransition Generated Duration just handles the time it takes to move from one State to another. However your Duration on the Storyboard will apply to that actual animation.